# Angular Jasmine Test : Expected spy to have been called

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am testing a confirmation dialog in Angular 8 and for some strange one test passes and the other fails when they are more or less similar. There are three statuses that I am testing.
Approve, Reject and Reset. The test for approve passes but fails for reset and reject. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be ?

The error that I am getting is

```
ApproveComponent should call reject confirmation dialog FAILED
Expected spy show to have been called.
```

**Test component**

```
 describe('ApproveComponent', () => {
      let component: ApproveComponent;
      let injector: TestBed;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<ApproveComponent>;
      const mockService: ApprovalsService = <ApprovalsService>{
        approve: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
        reset: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
        reject: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
        get: (type: string, id: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
      };
      const mockRoute = { params: of({ id: '123', type: 'test' }), snapshot: {} };

      function setupComponent(getResult: any = {}) {
        spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('approve')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
        spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('reset')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
        spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('reject')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
        spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('get')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(getResult));

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            DxTextAreaModule,
            DxButtonModule,
            SharedModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'approvals', component: ApproveComponent }])
          ],
          declarations: [ApproveComponent],
          providers: [
            { provide: ApprovalsService, useValue: mockService },
            { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockRoute },
            { provide: MessageService, useClass: MockMessageService },
            { provide: ConfirmationDialogService, useValue: ConfirmationDialogServiceMock },
            { provide: NgxPermissionsService, useClass: MockNgxPermissionsService }
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApproveComponent);
        injector = getTestBed();
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(true);

        fixture.detectChanges();
      }

      it('should create and call get', () => {
        setupComponent();

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        expect(mockService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });



      it('should call confirmation dialog when accept confirmation is called', () => {
        setupComponent();
        const dialogService = injector.get(ConfirmationDialogService);
        const dialogServiceSpy = spyOn(dialogService, 'show').and.returnValue({});
        component.showMessage = true;
        component.message = 'Approved because potato';
        fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Approve'));

        expect(dialogServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      fit('should call reject confirmation dialog', () => {
        setupComponent();
        const dialogService = injector.get(ConfirmationDialogService);
        const dialogServiceSpy = spyOn(dialogService, 'show').and.returnValue({});

        component.showMessage = true;
        component.message = 'rejected because potato';
        fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Reject'));
        expect(dialogServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(mockService.reject).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });


    });
```

**ApprovalComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-approve',
  templateUrl: './approve.component.html'
})

export class ApproveComponent {
  public showMessage = false;
  public message: string;
  public body = 'Loading content for approval...';
  public loading = true;
  private permissions: NgxPermissionsObject;
  private id: string;
  private type: string;
  private approvalMessage = 'Are you sure the information is correct and you want to approve?';
  private resetMessage = 'Are you sure you want to reset this approval back to the start?';
  private rejectMessage = 'Are you sure you want to reject this approval? ' +
    'Rejecting an approval is permanent and will close this process and prevent it progressing further.';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ApprovalsService,
    private ngxPermissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    public confirmationDialog: ConfirmationDialogService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.type = params['type'];
      this.loading = true;
      this.service.get(this.type, this.id).then(x => {
        if (!x) { return; }
        this.loading = false;
        this.body = x.body;
      });
    });
    this.permissions = this.ngxPermissionsService.getPermissions();
  }




  public confirmation = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve' ) => {
    if (!this.showMessage && (type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes) || (type !== 'Approve')) {
      this.showMessage = true;
      return;
    }

    if (!this.message && (type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes) || (type !== 'Approve')) {
      this.messageService.add('Message is required.', 'warning');
      return;
    }

    if (type === 'Approve') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.approvalMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reset') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.resetMessage , type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.rejectMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    }

  }

  public confirm = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve' ) => {
    let promise;

    if ( type  === 'Reset') {
      promise = this.service.reset(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
      promise = this.service.reject(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    } else if (type === 'Approve') {
      promise = this.service.approve(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    }


    promise.then(() => {
      this.messageService.add(`Successfully ${type}.`, 'info');
      this.navigateToApprovalList();
    });
  }


  private navigateToApprovalList = () => this.router.navigate(['/approvals']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. Basically the conditional logic needed to be changed from

```
if (!this.showMessage && (type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes) || (type !== 'Approve')) to  if (!this.showMessage && (type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes) || (type !== 'Approve'))
```

To

```
  if (!this.showMessage
      && ((type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes)
        || (type !== 'Approve')))
```